# Moving UITableView up in UIView not persisting

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController with a UIButton at the top and a UITableView just below it. The upper button is 'History' which I am setting as a feature the user can turn on or off. I set up the view controller using a XIB with the button and table.

When the 'history' feature is disabled, I want to hide the history button and move the top of my UITableView up accordingly so there is no white space at the top of my view.

When I call my hideHistory: method in viewDidAppear:, it does hide the history button and move the table up to the top of my view.

But after opening a modal view (to add a row to the table) and then closing the modal view, the table has moved back down to its original position. Adding the call to viewWillAppear: has no effect.

Below is the code for hideHistory. Any ideas on why the table is resetting to its original position?

Thanks in advance!

```
- (void)hideHistory
{
    [historyButton setHidden:YES] ;

    // move our data table up accordingly
    CGFloat newTop = historyButton.frame.origin.y ;

    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(dataTable.frame.origin.x,
                                 newTop,
                                 dataTable.frame.size.width,
                                 dataTable.frame.size.height);
    [dataTable setFrame:newFrame] ;

    [[self view] setNeedsLayout] ;
    [dataTable setNeedsLayout] ;
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that when the modal is dismissed the history button is hidden ?

Comment: Check if this is an effect of auto-layout (which is on by default).  If so you may want to do a similar thing in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, or solve it in a different way.

Comment: @meaning-matters. Thanks! It was the auto layout being enabled. When I turned it off, it works. For most of my views, I have turned off auto-layout. For whatever reason, I had not for this one. Thanks again!

Comment: @elio.d The history button is doing what I want. It is (well, was) the table view misbehaving.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off auto layout and placing the call in viewWillAppear: is the correct answer. When auto layout is turned off, the UITableView moves up properly and stays there. Also, the calls to [[self view] setNeedsLayout] and [dataTable setNeedsLayout] are not necessary.